# JBeret skippable exception thrown in ItemWriter triggers new chunk within the old transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsr352, jberet

Using JBeret I execute a simple job with single chunk based step which reads entries from the database, processes them and updates it. The step also defines a `ChunkListener` which interacts with the database as well and a list of skippable exception classes.

An example of such a job is:

```xml
<job id="testJob" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" version="1.0">
  <step id="test">
    <listeners>
      <listener ref="someChunkListener"/>
    </listeners>
    <chunk item-count="1" >
      <reader ref="testReader" />
      <processor ref="testProcessor"/>
      <writer ref="testWriter"/>
      <skippable-exception-classes>
        <include class="java.lang.IllegalStateException"/>
      </skippable-exception-classes>
    </chunk>
  </step>
</job>
```

I have observed the following flow:

1. Transaction has been started for the chunk
2. The `someChunkListener` `beforeChunk` is triggered
3. The `ItemReader` is triggered
4. The `ItemProcessor` is triggered
5. *The `ItemWriter` is triggered causing an `IllegalStateException`
6. *The `someChunkListener` `beforeChunk` is triggered
7. The `ItemReader` is triggered on new chunk
8. ...

What I found strange is that between step 5) and step 6) no new transaction is started, but
a new chunk has started/the chunk has restarted.

I tried looking into the `JSR-352` specification, but I could not find such behavior described. I looked at the pseudo codes provided there, but I could not find a single pseudo code which suggests that a new chunk may be started (`beforeChunk` on the chunk listener may be called) but the old transaction is used. I also looked at the JBeret implementation of `ChunkRunner` and it seems that the prevention of starting of a new transaction is intentional.

To me it seems natural that in this situation either no `beforeChunk` callback would be called (we continue in the same chunk) or a new transaction would exist for our chunk.

I'm worried that I cannot find a well specified transaction boundaries on chunk based jobs. How should I handle possible dirty transactions based on partially written items or updates from the chunk listeners or even sending a `JMS messages` via `XA Transaction`?

Is this behavior JBeret behavior described somewhere along with other similar behavior? Is it a bug, or something JSR-352 specific I didn't look at?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are seeing may have to do with the item-count = 1 in your job xml file. Since every single item has its own chunk, so a new chunk is started after skipping, hence calling the beforeChunk listener method.

Also because in the first chunk, the skippable exception caused the item to be skipped. As a result, there is nothing left to be committed, and active transaction continues onto the next iteration.

See Jakarta Batch spec [skippable exception section](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/batch-api/blob/master/spec/src/main/asciidoc/job_specification_language.adoc#skipping-exceptions).

[This batch spec issue](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/batch-api/issues/70) may be somewhat related.

Comment: I understand what you mean. But as far as I saw in the specification: "A failed commit will be treated the same as a failed write". I would assume that a failed write is equal to a failed commit which should rollback the transaction?

Comment: Also item-count =1 doesn't mean that the item itself failed. The item may be persisted into the database, but something else may have gone wrong in the writer after the persist of the item which I would assume should still rollback the persisted item. In the end of the line the item should be skipped when hitting the exception, not persisted.

Comment: Another dangerous behavior I saw as a result of this behavior is that if in the ItemProcessor  an entity has changed its state. The entityManager would still perfrom an update to the entity in the database, even though the writer failed (even if the writer did not explicitly update forced the update of the entity).

Comment: These are valid concerns. I'll need to check jberet `ChunkRunner` again to see if there are some conditions that guard against reusing dirty transactions, and I'm leaning towards there are some in place. Do you have reproducer that shows these specific issues?

Comment: Unfortunately, the environment (project) that I'm testing is proprietary, but the job I'm testing with is pretty similar as the one I described in my question. A simple entity holding attribute "name" is read once in the reader (after that reader returns null). Then in processor I set its name to be random UUID and in writer I throw IllegalStateException immediately. As a result I observe that the entity has updated its UUID in the database.

Comment: All I can see in regards starting a new transaction in the `ChunkRunner` is `(tm.getStatus() != Status.STATUS_ACTIVE)`. I don't really think that there is a reliable way to actually validate that transaction is dirty or not. At least not via using the Transaction API by itself.

Comment: We should take a close look at this part of [ChunkRunner](https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/blob/main/jberet-core/src/main/java/org/jberet/runtime/runner/ChunkRunner.java#L643-L655). Currently it only rolls back transaction that has already been marked rollback after a failure during item writing triggered a skippable exception. Need to think about if what to do with an active transaction before starting a new chunk.

Comment: I created a jira issue to track it: [JBERET-597](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/JBERET-597)

Comment: Thank you, you may create an answer I could accept.

Comment: @АндрейАндреев I proposed a pr to fix it, can you review it? https://github.com/jberet/jsr352/pull/381

Comment: I made some comments on the review. May check them out.